# JS: Creating n variables using for loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, variables, for-loop

If I have to create n variables `a_1`, `a_2`, `a_3` ... `a_n`, where n is determined during runtime, how will I be able to do it?

Obviously, this code won't work:

```js
var n = prompt("Enter number of variables?");
for (i=0; i<=n; i++) {
var a_i
}
```

As n is given by user it is not possible to pre-determine number of variables to be created.

In other words, Is it possible to create a variable with name from another variable in JS?

Comment: why not just use an array?

Comment: Can you explain why you need to do this?  This might be a use case for a JavaScript dictionary

Comment: @Mureinik i want this for matrices, and array of array is not allowed in js

Comment: @Legman I want to create a matrices with each row as an array and number of rows given by user, so i need this

Comment: @Abhishek actually an array of arrays is indeed allowed in JavaScript

Comment: you should create an Object outside the `for` loop and fill it up with data, so create `var obj = {}` then inside the `for` loop: `obj[i] = whatever`

Comment: How do you want to access your variables later if you don't know their names? Use an array.

Comment: @pointy I read somewhere that it isn't allowed

Comment: @alexP I cant create array, because the variables itself are arrays

Comment: @Abhishek you should give that book to somebody else. Array elements in JavaScript can be *anything*, including other arrays.

Comment: @pointy How to access an element in an array of array?

Comment: @Abhishek `array[x][y]`

Comment: @pointy Then it is same as multi dimensional arrays, I am sure that isn't a js feature

Comment: @Abhishek I have been writing JavaScript code for 20 years. There are definitely multi-dimensional arrays in the same way that Java has multi-dimensional arrays. You create an array, and then you initialize each element to a new array. The elements are accessed via two `[]` expressions, exactly as I wrote in the previous comment.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes, like this

```
for (i=0; i<=n; i++) {
window['a_'+i] = undefined;
}
```

Comment: that will create a global variable and not necessarily on the scope of the parent function

Comment: This would work but your should not do that. You should keep the number of properties assigned to `window` as small as possible. Use an own object instead.

Comment: @ManuallyOverriden I cannot understand the code at all, please explain

Comment: @Abhishek - this is just like what I told you in my comment to your question, only using a global scope (`window`) instead of local scope (local *object*)